# Question about ambiguity of possessives

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, possessives

per say X is an attribute or  part of the Ys, if I want to say

"my X is bigger than all of your Ys combined "

how do I make sure they do not misunderstand that I meant

"my X is bigger than all of your Ys' combined".

for example
my cannon is bigger than all of your tanks combined, as in I have a giant tank ,or my condo is bigger than all of your buildings combined

Comment: I think it's the apostrophe you're asking about. Apostrophes are not audible and are usually ignored, so you **can't** make sure nobody confuses it. The solution is not to use apostrophes in speech.

Comment: so if I say  my condo is bigger than all of your buildings combined, will people understand me? because condo is a part of a building. if not, how do I avoid the confusion?

Comment: Don't make comparisons of parts of buildings. If you want to be exact,  avoid ambiguity and try to make things clear. This is not done by adding or subtracting inaudible punctuation; it's done by being clear from the start. Are you talking square meters or cubic meters? Height or area? Number of rooms or number of floors? Comparisons are not simple.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** you are asking about

> My cannon is bigger than all of your tanks' cannons combined

and omitting the repeated *cannon* makes the resulting sentence ambiguous when it's spoken because an apostrophe is inaudible:

> My cannon is bigger than all of your tanks' combined
> My cannon is bigger than all of your tanks combined

If the ambiguity is unacceptable, the only recourse is to remove the apostrophe.

> My cannon is bigger than those of all of your tanks combined

But if you are simply talking about cannons then where they are doesn't matter:

> My cannon is bigger than all of yours combined

Comment: yeah, they are unable to distinguish between the plural and the apostrophe. the question here is how to use the plural form here, so that you are not misunderstood?

Comment: I've answered that. You can't.